# VBA-Excel : How can I verify if options->Formulas is set to automatic?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

So, I'm programming a macro and I'm not very "really good" at the moment in this kind of coding.

How can I verify if in the options->formulas is set to automatic in VBA Excel?

Thanks!

QcHaxing

Comment: *Verify?* If you want to check you can use `debug.print Application.Calculation` and it will tell you whether it is automatic or manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

To make the calculations manual:

```
Application.Calculation = xlManual
```

EDIT:

If you wish to "check" whether it Options->Formulas is set to automatic, you can do that.

```
If Application.Calculation = xlManual Then
    *** Do some action you desire, like printing "Yes" in A1, or something ***

Else
    *** Do some action you desire, like printing "No" in A1, or something ***
End If
```

Or, as @Masoud suggested:

```
debug.print Application.Calculation
```

Comment: Thanks! But do I have an option to "check" if the option is already "automatic" ?

Comment: If Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic Then ... End If

Comment: If you add `Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic` in your code, you will never need to check.  However, I suppose you could do some logic.  I will edit to show you.

Comment: NP. BTW, You should accept @E.Trauger 's answer. :-)

Comment: Cheers to you, @MikeJRamsey56 !